# Getting java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.swing") with JDK8?

Tags: java, swing, tomcat, applet

I am trying to run my applet with JDK8 but i'm getting below exception on java console at this line of my code

```
SplitPaneH = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
```

Traces

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.swing")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkPackageAccessHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.jb2011.lnf.beautyeye.ch17_split.BESplitPaneDivider.<init>(BESplitPaneDivider.java:77)
at org.jb2011.lnf.beautyeye.ch17_split.BESplitPaneUI.createDefaultDivider(BESplitPaneUI.java:54)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSplitPane.setUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSplitPane.updateUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSplitPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSplitPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JSplitPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
at TeleProvisionManager.InventoryPage.<init>(InventoryPage.java:382)
at TeleProvisionManager.MainFrame.createMainTab(MainFrame.java:2147)
at TeleProvisionManager.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:1253)
at TeleProvisionManager.LoginChangeGroupDlg.handleContinueButton(LoginChangeGroupDlg.java:791)
at TeleProvisionManager.LoginChangeGroupDlg.jbtnContinueActionPerformed(LoginChangeGroupDlg.java:489)
at TeleProvisionManager.LoginChangeGroupDlg.access$100(LoginChangeGroupDlg.java:56)
at TeleProvisionManager.LoginChangeGroupDlg$4.actionPerformed(LoginChangeGroupDlg.java:355)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRootPaneUI$Actions.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.UIManager$2.postProcessKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But it was worked well with JDK7. I am not getting what is the problem and how to solve it. And i tried downloading 'jsdg-stubs-jre1.5.jar' which contains sun.swing classes and copying that jar to WEB-INF/lib folder but no use. How to solve it please help me. TIA!

Comment: What operating system? What browser?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Windows and IE11

Comment: Does you applet try to connect back to the server once loaded? How many jars the applet needs?

Comment: applet need 13 jars

Comment: For me worked the `-nosecurity` option:
`javaws -nosecurity start.jnlp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"accessClassInPackage.sun.swing" which signifies that in Webstart it is not allowed to use the package sun.swing.
You need to sign your applet, and with latest jdk 8 security, will block any applet signed with an untrusted certificate authority.So if you self sign this applet put low the security settings.untill it executes.
As an example [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~crypto/fixjava.html).

The thing with java 8 is that we have the security level ranging from high to very high ,while on java 7 it ranged from medium and above.The setting was only intended to block malicious or unsigned apps in java 8.However sometimes it may cause trouble with active X controls.If your app is running using low setting ,good otherwise i suggest java7, unless you dont use enhanced features like lambda expressions and other stuff

Comment: i am using signed applet only still getting same error

Comment: Did you try lowering the security settings[here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)

Comment: which security settings i have to change Java or browser?

Comment: Follow the example above and try

Comment: already i did this, i can't change Java security level to Medium because i'm using JDK 8u31. So, i have added my site to Exception List.

Comment: If i add 'permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.swing" ' in java.policy it's working but i think that's not the proper way.

Comment: do you have any other ideas to specify RunTimePermission to applet?

Answer (score 2):

Between java7 and java8 there were a bunch of security restrictions added to the way applets are constrained in sandbox mode - especially in communicating over the network.

Check if anything [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/whatsnew_deployment.html#A1011429368) applies to your case - it may not be applicable, but these need to be checked anyway.